# How to update internal enterprise web page without Visual Studio project?

Tags: asp-classic

Problem 1 : I am not a web developer, but since people think all developers can do everything, I've been asked to look at a company's internal web site for the purpose of updating it.

Problem 2 : The company does not have the original Visual Studio project for the web site.

Question 1 : Can the files running the web site be used to manually build a working VS project?

Question 2 : Is it better or necessary to rebuild the web site from scratch?

Comment: if you have source code on IIS you can download it and open in VS. So it depends how website was deployed: compiled or just with source code.

Comment: I know that we can see, for example, the .asp files, open them in a text editor and see code.

Comment: .asp files or .aspx files? If they are .asp files you can edit them in notepad if you like.

Comment: .asp - The client provided the .asp file for the main landing page as a sample.

Comment: It it's asp and it is not complicated - just edit it in Notepad. I have a couple of old asp sites still running (with a lot of users) and I maintain/edit them in Microsoft Expression. (Actually, to be honest, I quite often open the pages on the live server in notepad and do the edits there! Ahh, happy days - no deploying problems at all!)

Comment: if website consists from asp files, you should change tag from asp.net to classical asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two are two ways to deploy ASP.NET:

1. Compile project and deploy aspx pages and dlls (I'm talking about webforms here, not MVC).
2. Source code (dynamic compilation available starting Framework 2)

In second case you can download all code, create project and add all files there.

If you have only complied version, it's more complex. You can get aspx files, but for code behind you can use for example Reflector or DotPeek.

PS. If you have ASP files, it's classic ASP, you have all source inside ASP (VBScript), so you can get everything and edit in VS or even in notepad.